# ¿Saben cómo publicar y usar paquetes NPM en GitHub enterprise?

Tags: github, npm

Tengo un repositorio en GitHub enterprise (está dentro de la organización asignada a la empresa en la que trabajo, `Org-Name` para efectos del ejemplo). Con mayúsculas y minúsculas en el nombre.

Hay un repositorio `repo_name` con un componente Angular que utilizamos como dependencia en otros proyectos Angular más complejos. Su ruta interna es `@Org-Name/repo_name`.

Cuando hago `npm publish` con toda la configuración requerida, se publica exitosamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, si lo uso en el package.json de, digamos, `Org-Name/otro_repo2`,

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@Org-Name/repo_name": "4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.8",
...
}
```

al hacer `npm -i` falla y me dice:

```
npm ERR! 404  '@Org-Name/repo_name@4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.8' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
```

¿Alguien sabe qué tipo de restricciones hay, si hay un bug o si debo configurar algo especial en el `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya GitHub hizo lo que sea que era necesario para poder publicar en el NPM asociado a un repo enterprise. Esencialmente, donde se requiera, hay que poner ese org-name todo en minúsculas y lo va a reconocer correctamente.

El .npmrc de su ambiente hay que configurarlo así:

```
@user-name:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<your_github_token>
```

Reemplazando por el token GitHub que usan para jalar y publicar cosas.

En el `/proyects/lib-name/package.json`, hay que cambiar el name a

`"name": "@org-name/lib-name"`

y hay que añadir

```
"repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "URL-LIB-REPO-GITHUB"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "registry":"https://npm.pkg.github.com"
    }
```

Reemplazando la URL por la URL del repo al que le vamos a asociar el artefacto

Por último, en el archivo `/src/package.json` hay que actualizar el nombre al nombre del repositorio, y hay que actualizar los scripts (build, publish, etc) para que usen el nombre nuevo de la librería (`"name"`).